# using random number in LESS CSS

Tags: css, random, less

Is there any way to use a random number in LESS?  I'm using less version 1.5, 
I have tried using

@var: `` `Math.random( ``)` ;

Comment: try to add backticks (`) around Math.random()

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - Why don't you post this as an answer.

Comment: @Danield because the link posted in the question has the code with backticks. Why should I duplicate the same answer? :)

Comment: @Danield - Because then the question should be closed as "just a spell error" rather than "duplicate".